# Cannot connect to mysql table using Lumen framework

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

Background: i installed php7.2 using brew then installed mysql using brew.
mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew). Then created my lumen project using composer
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen blog`

i'm trying to insert data into my table and it throws the error in postman
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'`

This is my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Lumen
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY= 9887765535434424354566gfr547633
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=pqueue
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_STRICT_MODE=false
DB_SOCKET=/tmp/mysql.sock

CACHE_DRIVER=array
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

in my config>database.php i have the default settings

return [

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4'),
        'collation' => env('DB_COLLATION', 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'),
        'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'strict' => env('DB_STRICT_MODE', true),
        'engine' => env('DB_ENGINE', null),
        'timezone' => env('DB_TIMEZONE', '+00:00'),
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 5432),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'schema' => env('DB_SCHEMA', 'public'),
        'sslmode' => env('DB_SSL_MODE', 'prefer'),
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 1433),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => env('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'),
        'prefix' => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
    ],

],
```

];
`

i'm not sure what could be the issue.

When i run php `artisan migrate:refresh` or `php artisan migrate --env=production`

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'pqueue'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.ta
  bles where table_schema = test and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')


In Connector.php line 70:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'pqueue'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

But i gave grant access to all tables in test database already
`GRANT ALL on test.* to pqueue@localhost;`

I was able to use pqueue credentials to create a table and insert data in the test database by using the mysql console. so i know the user has sufficient previllages.

Can some one please help me debug?

Comment: Access denied means incorrect user name or passeord.

Comment: `@'localhost'` implies that the database is running on your own system at home?  If this runs on a provider's infrastructure, 'localhost' does not work.  You have to specify the actual host (domain) that the provider give you.  And your database.php does not specify the user / password you talk about above.

Comment: @Nic3500 yes the db is running on my local machine as well..in the database.php it uses the credentials from the env file unless not specified it would use the values specified in the database.php . And like the error states it get the username pqueue from the env file

Comment: @Shadow, Using those same credentials i was able to login into mysql, create a table as well as insert into that table. So i dont think there is anything wrong with the credentials. For some reason the framework code is not able to valid the user correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue.In case if anybody else has a similar issue, please make sure your mysql user's password does not have a "#" in it.